# Main content slider suggestion with existing nav

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, navbar

I am trying to make a content slider on an existing html page.
Basically, when the user clicks on a navigation link, the content will 'slide out' the current page and 'slide in' the corresponding one.

I have used sliders in the past, but not tied to a already existing nav bar.

Any suggestion?

My html structure is like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="navlink">item</li>
    <li class="navlink">item</li>
    <li class="navlink">item</li>
    <li class="navlink">item</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="content">
     content
  </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can take a look at this, made a pretty simple script.

**Working Example:**
http://jsfiddle.net/9rde7/6/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="navlink" page="page1">item</li>
    <li class="navlink" page="page2">item</li>
    <li class="navlink" page="page3">item</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="content">
     <div class="content-page active" id="page1">Content 1</div>
     <div class="content-page" id="page2" style="background:#666">Content 2</div>
     <div class="content-page" id="page3">Content 3</div>
  </div>
</div>​​​​​​
```

**CSS:**

```
.content{
    background:#efefef;
    position:relative;
    width:99%;
    height:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.content-page{
    background:#dddddd;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    left:100%;
}

.content-page.active{
    left:0;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('.nav li').bind('click', function(){
    $page = $('#'+$(this).attr("page"));
    if($page.hasClass("active")) return;

    $('.content-page.active').animate({left:"100%"},200);
    $('.content-page').removeClass("active");
    $page.animate({left:"0"},200, function(){$page.addClass("active");});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean "page transitions"?  There are a bunch of different ways to do it, including [this previous SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166510/how-to-slide-an-entire-page-on-load-with-jquery), or [this fading one](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2010/02/23/how-to-use-jquery-to-make-slick-page-transitions/).

Comment: Yes, when a user clicks on a navigation link, the content div will either load in a new page, or make a transition to an already loaded-in-DOM div. I'm looking for a sliding effect rather than fadein-fadeout. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: here's a cheap and easy sliding one  http://www.fasw.ws/faswwp/non-jquery-page-transitions-lightweight/
also, this one http://css.dzone.com/articles/html-page-slide-without